# Javafx calling javascript to excute java function in webview not working

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, javafx-webengine

According to the JavaFX docs, you can execute Java code with JavaScript function. Below is my code:

```
engine = webview.getEngine();
engine.load("http://localhost:8080/testing.php");
openExcel callback = new openExcel();
JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
window.setMember("app", callback);
```

The above is in the initialize method, then for the other class(openExcel) I've got something like this:

```
public class openExcel {

    public void open() {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\v3.01.xlsm");
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Your application is not support");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

HTML file:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function openExcel() {
                app.open();
                alert('hello world');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="openExcel()">Open excel</button>
    </body>
```

The problem that I'm facing is that when I click in the button "openExcel" it does nothing? I need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your problem and it seems like your bridge is throwing error/message and you can't see the output. I used your code to create a simple test with JavaScript message listener:

```
public class WebEngineTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener((webView, message, lineNumber, sourceId) -> {
            System.out.println(message + "[at " + lineNumber + "]");
        });

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.loadContent("<html><head><script>function openExcel() { app.open(); alert('hello world'); } </script></head><body><button onclick=\"openExcel()\">Open excel</button></body></html>");

        JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
        window.setMember("app", new OpenExcel());

        Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 300, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class OpenExcel {

        public void open() {
            if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Desktop is not supported");
            }

            try {
                File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\v3.01.xlsm");
                // File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\dzikoysk\\Desktop\\panda.txt");
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Your application is not support");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

If I remove `System.out.println(message + "[at " + lineNumber + "]");` and file does not exist or desktop is not supported then **nothing happens** but with the message listener:

[image: Console Exception Preview]

So I've updated `myFile` to `new File("C:\\Users\\dzikoysk\\Desktop\\panda.txt");` that exists on my PC and now everything works:

[image: App Preview]

Anyway, in your code `</html>` tag is missing. In some older versions of WebEngine it can also cause problems, be careful with details like that - the engine has a lot of bugs and not implemented features.

Comment: I've added the missing html tag and now it is working find !! thank you !